# Why is the sound of the alphabet "j" different in Spanish, English, German and French?

Tags: pronunciación, español-neutral

The alphabet "j" is pronounced differently in the following major European languages:

- Spanish: justo `/ˈxusto/`
- English:  just  `/d͡ʒʌst/`
- German: junge `/ˈjʊŋə/`
- French:  juste  `/ʒyst/`

How is the sound so varied in these languages?

Comment: @Rodrigo cancelé el bounty (se te reintegró la reputación), pues ya se preguntó en otro sitio donde es más apropiada. En el siguiente comentario lo explico mejor. Ya lo siento pero creo que era lo que se debía hacer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question was also asked in [Linguistics.se]: [How is it that such varied sounds (in major European Languages) came to be represented by the same letter “j”?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/8730/10160). Since [Cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites IS NOT permitted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/209901), I am closing this one since it is more on topic in Linguistics than here.

Comment: @fedorqui OK, tienes toda la razón.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the pronunciation is so different is because a phenomenon called *phoneme change*.

The term is used to design the process from which a language changes their phonetic system over time. It is a universal and inevitable process whereby the languages chance over time and whereby the stages of the language of different periods can develop 
intelligibility among them.

---

### Types of changes:

---

**Assimilation**: Process where a sound acquires phonetic features which make them more similar to an adjacent 
phoneme or a close 
phoneme, the
phoneme is "assimilated"

**Metathesis**: It is the change of place of one or more sounds in the interior of a word. It responds to the need of making the pronunciation easier, like crocodilo ->cocodrilo.

Therefore, the languages you mentioned and asked about have changed over time because of the reasons above.

*Note*: Language has evolved vastly over time, Spanish of 200 years isn't the same as current Spanish. So if a language in a single country can change so much, imagine how could languages that have the same roots can also vastly evolve; specially when there is a far location among them.

(Bibliography: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambio_fon%C3%A9tico , https://prezi.com/2dwuqb5kxl58/cambios-foneticos-morfologicos-y-semanticos/)

Answer (score 2):

I would reverse the question.  How is it that such varied sounds came to be represented by the same letter?  It is the oral language that is the natural language.  The written language is added later.

In Spanish,  the sound that is represented by the jota used to be represented by the equis.  Examples:  Mexico, Texas.  The change was part of a general revision of spelling.

Comment: A good point. I will go ahead and put your version of the question on Linguistics section.

Comment: Thanks. It's also worth noting that the sound of the words "Mexico" and "Texas" in American English appear to be derived from the way an American would pronounce an equis, and not by listening to a Mexican saying those words.

Comment: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/8730/5306

Comment: I disagree, to a point. While it is true that oral language comes first, it also evolves after the written form is established. The letter *j* in these languages, or in some of them at least, did not sound the way it sounds today when it was first written. But I don't know enough of this to write a full answer.

Comment: I also don't know enough about the other languages that use j for various sounds.  But in the case of Spanish, the spelling was changed to provide a new use  for the letter j.  Example:  Mexico became Mejico, although it is still spelled with an x in Mexico.